# Object with id does not exist in $sysregistries when starting hyperledger composer v0.19.x network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have recently upgraded my Hyperledger Composer project from 0.16.x to 0.19.4 using the https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org tutorial. Since the upgrade my `composer network start` throws a lot of exceptions.

```
composer network start --card PeerAdmin@vecozo-gts-network-patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter-patient-pieterpost -n vecozo-gts-network -V 0.0.8 -o endorsementPolicyFile=endorsement-policy_gtschannel-patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.json -A patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.patient-pieterpost.admin -C identities/patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.patient-pieterpost.admin/admin-pub.pem -A patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.zorgverlener-zorgpeter.admin -C identities/patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.zorgverlener-zorgpeter.admin/admin-pub.pem
```

The command completes succesfully:

```
Starting business network vecozo-gts-network at version 0.0.8

Processing these Network Admins:
        userName: patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.patient-pieterpost.admin
        userName: patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.zorgverlener-zorgpeter.admin

✔ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Successfully created business network cards:
        Filename: patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.patient-pieterpost.admin@vecozo-gts-network.card
        Filename: patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.zorgverlener-zorgpeter.admin@vecozo-gts-network.card

Command succeeded
```

But when I check the logs of the `dev-peer0.patient-pieterpost.vecozo-gts.nl-vecozo-gts-network-0.0.8-xxx` container, there are many errors:

```
{"log":"E0507 08:24:59.671104376      17 ssl_transport_security.cc:238] Could not get common name of subject from certificate.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:24:59.671668775Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.294Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AssetRegistry' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.294925522Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.355Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.356149858Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.399Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.TransactionRegistry' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.399291913Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.414Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.414653497Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.445Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.445298765Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.485Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.485398523Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.508Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.508250099Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.529Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RemoveAsset' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.530641775Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.575Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.576106228Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.596Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateParticipant' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.598118605Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.633Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RemoveParticipant' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.633998767Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.656Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.656392444Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.674Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.IssueIdentity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.674834724Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.693Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.BindIdentity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.693227305Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.722Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ActivateCurrentIdentity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.722364674Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.747Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RevokeIdentity' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.747259448Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.776Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.StartBusinessNetwork' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.776830317Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.820Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ResetBusinessNetwork' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.823802868Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.867Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.SetLogLevel' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.867322523Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.890Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:vecozo.gts.model.Toestemming' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.890539098Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.937Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:vecozo.gts.model.ToegekendeToestemming' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:00.937697649Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.031Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Asset:vecozo.gts.model.Data' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.03227245Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.064Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Participant:vecozo.gts.model.Patient' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.064748416Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.116Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Participant:vecozo.gts.model.Zorgverlener' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.116382662Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.156Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Participant:vecozo.gts.model.RaadplegendZorgverlener' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.157089719Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.195Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Participant:vecozo.gts.model.DossierhoudendZorgverlener' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.195177979Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.239Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:vecozo.gts.model.ToestemmingToekenning' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.239309633Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.295Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:vecozo.gts.model.DataVerzoek' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.295292474Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.319Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:vecozo.gts.model.DataOverdracht' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.325926742Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.356Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:vecozo.gts.setup.model.SetupPatientAndZorgverlener' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.357298609Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.391Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:vecozo.gts.setup.model.SetupToestemmingenVoorPatient' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.391771073Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.412Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'Transaction:vecozo.gts.setup.model.SetupToegekendeToestemmingVoorPatient' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.41393655Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.448Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.448731414Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.448Z [2357af40] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {\"stack\":[\"{Error}Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist\",\"    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)\",\"    at \u003canonymous\u003e\",\"    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)\"]}\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.449312913Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.454Z [2357af40] INFO     :IdentityManager          :\u003cResourceManager\u003e()       Binding in the tx names and impl\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.454382508Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.486Z [2357af40] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()   created historian record\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.487022673Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.514Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.514227445Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.514Z [2357af40] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {\"stack\":[\"{Error}Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist\",\"    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)\",\"    at \u003canonymous\u003e\",\"    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)\"]}\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.514443545Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.545Z [2357af40] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()   created historian record\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.545746512Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.559Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.patient-pieterpost.admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.559436898Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.559Z [2357af40] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {\"stack\":[\"{Error}Object with ID 'patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.patient-pieterpost.admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.patient-pieterpost.admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist\",\"    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)\",\"    at \u003canonymous\u003e\",\"    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)\"]}\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.559642197Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.616Z [2357af40] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()   created historian record\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.617678937Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.710Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.zorgverlener-zorgpeter.admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.710461939Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.710Z [2357af40] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {\"stack\":[\"{Error}Object with ID 'patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.zorgverlener-zorgpeter.admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'patient-pieterpost-zorgverlener-zorgpeter.zorgverlener-zorgpeter.admin' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not exist\",\"    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)\",\"    at \u003canonymous\u003e\",\"    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)\"]}\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.710673639Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.722Z [2357af40] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()   created historian record\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.722872226Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.746Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.749317299Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.748Z [2357af40] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {\"stack\":[\"{Error}Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist\",\"    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)\",\"    at \u003canonymous\u003e\",\"    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)\"]}\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.749359699Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.765Z [2357af40] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.765400982Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.765Z [2357af40] ERROR    :Resolver                 :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship {\"stack\":[\"{Error}Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not exist\",\"    at NodeDataCollection.get (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)\",\"    at \u003canonymous\u003e\",\"    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)\"]}\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.765526182Z"}
{"log":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.774Z [2357af40] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()   created historian record\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-05-07T08:25:01.774817272Z"}
```

I can't find the problem that is causing these errors.

Comment: The first error is an SSL error, so I would suggest clearing that error to start with.  Perhaps looking at the volume mapping lines in your docker .yaml files will yield some inconsistency.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem? I have the same problem, but could find the solution.